# Best suitable transaction isolation level when business rules are not strict

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

Short version:
I am trying to determine which is the best transaction isolation level for the SQL server in our premises.

Long version:
I am extracting data from API calls and loading it into staging tables which then are incrementally loaded into destination tables. These destination tables are used in multiple ways, some of which are mentioned below:

1. Load data into a CRM through SSIS
2. Feed PowerBI reports (scheduled refreshes)
3. Apply business transformations to the data and load it into a Data Warehouse
4. Extract data into excel documents
5. (Most importantly) Do changes to the destination tables outside of the initial ETL process (From API to Staging to Destination)

Due to the large datasets, the issues I am facing are:

1. Deadlocks which I avoid by utilizing temporary tables and CTEs
2. Long waits between the updates of the tables (since one stored procedure that updates a destination table may wait up to an hour until this table is not used by another update)
3. Long PowerBI refresh waits and sometimes refresh timeouts when the SQL tables are being updated
4. Long Select statement waits when the SQL tables are being updated

Given that:

1. The industry I'm working is not banking or a sort of industry in which the data needs to be 100% accurate all the time
2. The PowerBI reports refresh only twice a day
3. I urgently need to utilize the data in those destination tables for other reporting purposes too
4. The datasets contain millions of records

What isolation level is suitable for this occasion? Or would it be better to set individual isolation levels through table hints?

Note1 : My employer and I would not mind if we had some dirty reads in the report refreshes as long as this means the reports refresh in a consequent manner and the tables can be used in other stored procedures (both read and update) without having to wait.

Note2 : The is_read_committed_snapshot_on is 0 in our SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

READ COMMITTED with READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION set for the database will enable readers to read without getting blocked by writers, prevent the writers from being blocked by the readers, and it doesn’t cause dirty reads.

So that’s the obvious first step.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am not a dba and these advices are really helpful. So, obvious first step is enabling the is_read_committed_snapshot_on. It may use more space in the tempdb due to the snapshots but it will make the reads not having to wait for an update to finish and vice versa.

Comment: As a second step, if I had to use table hints, would it be worth it to select data with (NOLOCK)? Judging by the fact that it's a production environment and therefore dirty reads are better than no reads at all, if that makes sense. Alternatively, would it be worth it to change the isolation level to READ UNCOMMITTED for the same reasons?

Comment: Dirty reads are not better than no reads at all because wrong results are not better than no results.  And dirty reads give you wrong results.  Read Committed Snapshot Isolation is all you need.

Comment: As a second step, turn on the Query Store so you can monitor resource use by queries, once the sessions no longer block each other. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I would recommend a different approach.  Instead of worrying about isolation level - you should rebuild the load process so that you are loading an 'offline' version of the table.  Once the table is loaded and ready you then modify the synonyms referring to the table to 'switch' to the updated table.  To switch, you drop the synonyms - and recreate them to the opposite table.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , I am making those changes today and monitoring the resources spent in the scheduled queries throughout the day. Hopefully this will make things faster. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jeff , thanks for the suggestion. I have never heard of synonyms, so I am having a look now. So, a synonym is a reference to a table as I understand. So, if I understood correctly your suggestion, there will be two identical versions (VersionA and VersionB) for each destination table. Each of them will be alternating in each run, from Online to Offline in the following manner:  ---Executing Run1(Loading_VersionA). At the end, VersionA will turn Online and VersionB Offline.    ----Executing Run2 (Loading_VersionB). At the end, VersionA will turn Offline and VersionB Online.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks! I'll try this shortly!